# Getting Nullpointer exception when using click method using Page object model

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, maven

In Helpers class I have this below method

```
public void click(By locator){
    driver.findElement(locator).click();
}
```

In one of the pages used that method to click on an element as follows

```
public class HomePage {
    public  WebDriver driver;
    Locators locator = new Locators();
    //DriverSettings ds =new DriverSettings();
    Helpers helper; 
    
    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
        helper= new Helpers(driver);
    }
    
    
    public void clickHomeLink(){
        
        helper.click(locator.HOMEPAGE_LINK_JAVA);
        
    }
```

Now in test.java class trying to click on click method is throwing a nullpointer exception which is pointing at `com.functional.utilities.Helpers.click(Helpers.java:42) at com.functional.pages.HomePage.clickHomeLink(HomePage.java:31)`.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HomeJava extends BaseClass {
    
    private BaseClass baseobj = new BaseClass();
    public WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void testHomePage(){
        baseobj.getDriverSettings().StartBrowser("Chrome", "https://www.javatpoint.com/");
        baseobj.getHomePage().clickHomeLink();
    }
}
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Where have you initialise HomePage object?

Comment: what is your baseclass ? why have you added the homepage class when you are not calling that anywhere in your homejava !

Answer (score 1):

Your base class should contain a driver initialization. Something like

```
public void setUp() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() // if you are using Chrome
}
```

Comment: Also you should mind the scope of that reference. In your example it would be only visible in scope of `setUp()` method